# can't get auto zooming on current location to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm trying to get my current location to zoom in automatic in mkmapview, but i can't get it to work.
here´s a bit of code, that i want is to zoom automatic like in Runkeeper.

```
**the h-file**

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>



@interface WalkingTableViewController: UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property ( strong, nonatomic) MKMapView *mapView;


@end



**the m-file**

    #import "WalkingTableViewController.h"

    @interface WalkingTableViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation WalkingTableViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad

    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
        self.mapView.delegate = self;
        [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];

        // zoom in on users location (?)
    }

    @end
```

Comment: How is mapView created?  If you have an MKMapView in a storyboard/xib, shouldn't the mapView property be an IBOutlet and be connected to that MKMapView?

Comment: the mapView is crated with an IBOutlet connected to the MKMapView.. but i can't get it to work

Comment: Your mapView property does not show the IBOutlet keyword, so I guess they are not properly connected. Also the mapView property should be weak, as the view is already held strongly by the view controller. I think, in your almost same question earlier today, you were a step closer to your solution. See my answer there. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/25844229/2460958

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the region, something like:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(_mapView.userLocation.coordinate,10000,10000);

[_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

The 10000 is the distance from your center point you want to see in your map.

Answer (score 0):

This should work like a charm

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(your_lat, yout_longitude, 1000.0, 1000.0);
        region.span.latitudeDelta = MAX(region.span.latitudeDelta, (coord.latitude - coord.latitude) * 1.05);
        region.span.longitudeDelta = MAX(region.span.longitudeDelta, (coord.longitude + coord.longitude) * 1.05);
        mapView.region = region;
```