# mapview autozoom on current location automatic

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, zooming

I have one problem. I've been looking at the other answers here on stack overflow about the same question and I can't get them to work for me. So I'm going to try asking here. What I want to do is when I'm on map view and have got the user location I want to automatically zoom into the location.

**the h-file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface WalkingTableViewController: UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>




@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *MKMapView;







@end
```

**the m-file**

```
#import "WalkingTableViewController.h"


@interface UITableViewController ()

@end

@implementation WalkingTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.MKMapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
    self.MKMapView.delegate = self;
    [self.MKMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];



}



- (IBAction)StopButton:(id)sender 

- (IBAction)StartButton:(id)sender 



@end
```

Comment: what i want is that its gonna zoom in like in the RunKeeper application

Comment: How do you "have the user location"? Is it coming in regularly via a CLLocationManager or do you have a value stored and you're just going to zoom in once (i.e. it doesn't change when the phone moves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to see the zoom animated, I would place the code in the viewDidAppear method, so that the animation starts once the view controller is displayed.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CLLocationManager* tempLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    MKCoordinateRegion tRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([tempLocationManager.location coordinate], 20000, 20000);
    [self.MKMapView setRegion:tRegion animated:animated];
}
```

Adjust the region (zoom level, 20000 in the example above) to your needs.

Comment: I can't see how this would work, at least not reliably. There's not enough time for the `tempLocationManager` to get a proper location fix so unless the GPS is already up and running you'll be getting a nil `location`.

Comment: You're right, the location manager reference should be held by the view controller, or - if used through the whole app - in the app delegate. This is what I do, when using CLLocationManager. I haven't thought about reference counting, when trying to provide a simple code example for this question.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is tell the mapview to zoom into a region. This should get you started:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = _mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, MKCoordinateSpanMake(2000, 2000));
[_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```